# How to interrupt current request, Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery, xmlhttprequest, interrupt-handling

My website on GAE-Python has a function to calculate some math using Evolutionary Optimization Algorithm, which will be called by an ajax request when the user click a button. Each request usually takes very long time to finish calculation.

I need some way (ajax or other methods) to tell the server to cancel the current request rather than using ajax's `xhr.abort()` function which does not stop the calculation on server side.

For an early attempt, I have found that GAE has the Request Timer in which the `DeadlineExceededError` will be raised by the runtime if the request takes too long to finish.

Based on this idea, **I would like to ask if there is a way to send a signal to the server to cause the runtime to trigger an interrupt on the request?**

Comment: There isn't.  You will either hit a DeadLineExceededError after 60 seconds or you requests terminates (returns) under your control.

Comment: If you think the request needs longer than 60 seconds and you want more control I suggest you use a task (can run for 10mins) and it can monitor memcache state.  Your front end request could also check periodically for a memcache state. This will also require threading, or async tasks and futures

Comment: You will need a seperate handler (and probably a token so that the request can identify what memcache key to monitor), that receives the cancel request and sets a key/value in memcache.

Comment: There is no signal you can send.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to do *any* long-running tasks synchronously in a handler. This is the perfect candidate for a [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push). The Ajax request should simply push the task onto the queue, and App Engine will process it offline. Tasks get a ten-minute timeout.

You can use memcache or the datastore to pass information to and from your Ajax code. For instance, the task handler could check memcache every few seconds for the existence of a 'stop_processing_FOO' key (where FOO is a unique ID generated by the Ajax when the task is first triggered), and the your 'cancel' button would call a handler to insert that key into memcache.

Similarly, the task could put a 'finished_processing_FOO' key with the associated values into memcache when it finishes, and your Ajax could periodically poll a handler that checks if that key is present, and return the value if so.